# Specify default rpm querytags

Tags: linux, rpm

I am working on 64 bits RHEL and I want rpm -q to use these tags by default:

```
'%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}'
```

Other than typing the tags by hand or defining an alias, is there a way I can configure this in ~/.rpmrc or another config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%_query_all_fmt` macro defines what format is used. Set it in `~/.rpmmacros`.

```
%_query_all_fmt %{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Before I accept your answer, can you please tell me where you found this? I searched for the answer but couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: I can't remember. I've been using rpm for... about a decade, and it's one of the things I picked up along the way. Anyways, `rpm --showrc` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I found below output most practical:

```
rpm -q --qf \
    '%{name}-%|epoch?{%{epoch}:}:{}|%{version}-%{release}%|arch?{.%{arch}}:{}|\n'
```

in `~/.rpmmacros` you can skip adding `\n` at the end of the format. Basically it skips displaying `%{epoch}` or `%{arch}` if package doesn't have it set. For example see output of `rpm -q tar openssl bind-libs perl-CGI gpg-pubkey` on *Scientific Linux 6.2*.